# Unique file system for multiple domains in Domain Access

Tags: domain-access, files

I have created five domains using domain access module like

- test1.com
- test2.com
- test3.com
- etc,

Now i want each users from different domains have to use unique file system in order to upload media.
From that i don't what users from other domains can access remaining domain's file system.

for example test1.com users can access only their own file system called test1.

Is there any way to do this in Domain Access Module? or any other module & Coding is needed?

Answer (score 0):

There is a sandbox module that appears to do what you need: https://github.com/markwk/domain_files

Essentially it extends the DrupalPrivateStreamWrapper class to provide a file path for each domain.

There is more discussion on d.o here with other methods people have tried: https://www.drupal.org/node/198131

Comment: I see. That module just works with private file downloads? I don't know if that's the use-case most people are after. They want separate files per domain in the admin UI.